# Disallow Special Characters From WOOCOMMERCE Username Signup

Tags: woocommerce, registration

I've tried many filters, but I can't seem to figure this one out. Something like this should do the trick, but no matter what I've tried, users can still include special characters in their username.

Here's the thing. This works as expected when using the standard Wordpress Registration. But with Woocommerce registration, this does not work! :(

```
 //add a filter to invalidate a username with spaces,special characters, capital letter, dot
add_filter('validate_username','restrict_space_in_username',10,2);
function restrict_space_in_username($valid,$user_name){
 //check if there is an space
 if ( preg_match('/\s[!@#$%^&*()+=\-\[\]\';,.\/{}|":<>?~\\\\][A-Z](.)/',$user_name) )
 return false;//if myes, then we say it is an error
 return $valid;//otherwise return the actual validity
}
```

Comment: Your regex does not work for me. Maybe you want something like /[\s!@#$%^&*()+=\-\[\]\';,.\/{}|":<>?~\\\\]/ instead?

Comment: Thanks! But, I have tested it and it works for the regular Wordpress login form (5.9). The problem is that it does not work in the Woocommerce signup.